# Method which would prompt the user for input and then output that same input, replacing each space with three periods (...)

Tags: python

```
txt = input("Please type in your text here ")

txt = txt.expandtabs(3)

print(txt)
```

I found this built-in method in the python documentation but it doesn't seem to do the job. Which method should I go for instead?
The goal here is to render 3 periods (...) for every empty space the user types in.

Comment: Based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.expandtabs I'm not sure why you expected that _would_ do the job.

Comment: you would probably be better serverd with `str.replace` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expandtabs()` is used for setting the tab size and not replacing the spaces. However, you can use `str.replace()` to replace any given substring with another.

```
txt = input("Please type in your text here ")
txt = txt.replace(' ', '...')
print(txt)
```